# Why is an inter-casting to Object required when casting among Class objects?

Tags: java, generics, casting

*I stumbled over a weird piece of code, and though I'm aware it semantically makes limited sense, I'm curious how/why it works that way.
For more clarity, this is just a minimal example reproducing it.*

Assume we have the following classes:

- `Housing<T>`
- `Cave<T extends Animal> extends Housing<T>`
- `Animal`

Now there's a method, let's call it `setHousing`, which accepts a `Class<? extends Housing<?>>` as argument.
We want to call it with our `Cave` class, e.g. like this:

```
setHousing(Cave.class);
```

However, this results in a compilation error, as `Class<Cave>` does not comply with `Class<? extends Housing<?>>`, because the compiler doesn't consider `Cave` a subclass of `Housing<?>` due to the generic `<?>` (right?).

So we try to cast this one to the correct type:

```
setHousing((Class<Housing<?>>) Cave.class);
```

But this results in another compilation error, claiming `Cannot cast from Class<Cave> to Class<Housing<?>>`. Why isnt't this possible?

To finally make it work, we need to cast to `Object` first:

```
setHousing((Class<Housing<?>>) (Object) Cave.class);
```

**What exactly is going on here; i.e. why does the third example work, but the second one doesn't?**

Comment: because `Class<Housing>` is not `Class<Cave>`, and compiler knows that. In third example, you first "mask" compile-time type by `Object`, then perform an unchecked cast.

Comment: to avoid this, you can do `setHousing((Class) Cave.class)`. This will fire a "rawtypes" warning, but at least you'll get rid of wierd double cast.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Hmm, so it boils down to the fact that classes with generic types are not convertible, even though the generic types themselves are compatible, is that correct?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach: Yes